# Windows phone Show/Hide textbox based on checkbox selection

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, windows-phone

I would show/hide textbox based on checkbox selection (if checked, show the textbox filed).
I tried this way, but it does't work ( the textbox field is always hidden):

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkpsw" IsChecked="{ Binding PasswordRequired, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Password,Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding PasswordRequired, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

**PasswordRequired** is a bool property, **Password** is a string property, 
**VisibilityConverter**:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool visibility = (bool)value;
    return visibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

My Model:

```
private bool _passwordRequired;
...
public bool PasswordRequired
{
    get { return _passwordRequired; }
    set
    {
        _passwordRequired = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PasswordRequired");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code above looks fine provided that `DataContext` set up properly and no binding error. Check output window to see if any binding error happen

Comment: no error in output window. Binding is correct, everything works...
    StkPnl.DataContext = Settings;

Comment: could you post your model/viewmodel where `PasswordRequired` property defined, or at least `PasswordRequired` definition? does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and do you raise property changed notification event in the property setter?

Comment: hi, I updated the first post

Comment: okay, still fine so far. I tried to create new WP project, and your code worked perfectly fine, the textbox got shown/hidden according to checkbox state. The problem must be somewhere else, not sure where.

Comment: thanks for the help. I will do other tests

Comment: Put a breakpoint here `return visibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;` and check if it does pass by here when you click on the checkbox

Comment: @tommy86 Try to set `IsChecked` property of CheckBox element to the `Visibility` property of Textbox element.                          `Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkpsw, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"`